# firestore admin upload file Error: Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to my Firebase's Cloud Firestore using Admin SDK in a node.js backend. Here below are my codes:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "something.appspot.com.appspot.com"
});
var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

bucket.upload('ns_icon.png').then(() => {
    console.log("uploaded");
})
```

The codes below yield an error message of:

```
server is running on port: 8000
(node:37108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not Found
    at new ApiError (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Hugue\Startups\Pllanet\Tech\Admin Console\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:59:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Hugue\Startups\Pllanet\Tech\Admin Console\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:194:38)      
    at Util.handleResp (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Hugue\Startups\Pllanet\Tech\Admin Console\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:135:117)
    at C:\Users\PC\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Hugue\Startups\Pllanet\Tech\Admin Console\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\build\src\util.js:434:22
    at onResponse (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Hugue\Startups\Pllanet\Tech\Admin Console\node_modules\retry-request\index.js:214:7)
    at C:\Users\PC\OneDrive - University of Waterloo\Hugue\Startups\Pllanet\Tech\Admin Console\node_modules\teeny-request\build\src\index.js:150:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:37108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting 
a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:37108) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The file which has the upload codes is in the same directory of `ns_icon.png`, which is the root directory. Did I specify the path wrong?

Comment: The documentation suggests that you're supposed to pass the fully qualified path name of the file to upload.  https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload

Answer (score 1):

I did not succeed to upload a file using Firebase admin. But I was able to use Google Cloud to do it like below:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'xxxxx',
    keyFilename: 'serviceAccount.json'
});
const bucket = storage.bucket("zzzzz");

// Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
bucket.upload('ns_icon.png', function(err, file) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("success");
    }
    else {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```